# How to map an array to another array and reset its keys in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object that has unique keys and each key holds an object:

```js
  var object = { 'a': {    
      source: '5279edf0-cd7f-11e3-af07-59475a41e2e9',
      target: 'f6b3faa1-ad86-11e3-9409-3dbc47429e9f',
      id: [ 'bf504d02-81e2-4a92-9c5c-8101943dc36d' ],
      edge_context: [ 'small' ],
      statement_id: [ '09b05bc0-20ab-11e9-a5b3-9fb3da66a7cb' ],
      weight: 2 
      }, 
      'b': {
      source: '5279edf1-cd7f-11e3-af07-59475a41e2e9',
      target: 'f6b3faa1-ad86-11e3-9409-3dbc47429e9f',
      id: [ 'de769846-9145-40f8-ab2d-91c0d9b82b27',
       'd5723929-71a0-4dfe-bf03-94d43e358145' ],
      edge_context: [ 'small' ],
      statement_id: 
      [ '09b05bc0-20ab-11e9-a5b3-9fb3da66a7cb',
       '62671510-20ab-11e9-8cbf-ef11fdb08712' ],
       weight: 6 
       }
    }
    
    
    var newArray = [];
    
    for (let item of object) {
            newArray(item);
    }
    
    console.log(newArray);
```

I want to map it to another array where the keys will be in a sequence `0, 1, 2` etc as the usual array

I tried to use this function above but it's not working saying "object is not iterable" so how to iterate the object?

Comment: `var array = [ 'a': {` That's not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Your array is invalid.

Comment: what is wrong with it?

Comment: `Object.values(object)`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
const mappedObject = Object.keys(object).map(
    k => object[k]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, change the structure. It could be in the following way (you will obtain an array of objects, which you will be able to access using indexes like 0, 1, 2, etc):

```
var objt = [ 
    {"a": {    
      "source": "5279edf0-cd7f-11e3-af07-59475a41e2e9",
      "target": "f6b3faa1-ad86-11e3-9409-3dbc47429e9f",
      "id": [ "bf504d02-81e2-4a92-9c5c-8101943dc36d" ],
      "edge_context": [ "small" ],
      "statement_id": [ "09b05bc0-20ab-11e9-a5b3-9fb3da66a7cb" ],
      "weight": 2 
      }
    }, 
    {"b": {
      "source": "5279edf1-cd7f-11e3-af07-59475a41e2e9",
      "target": "f6b3faa1-ad86-11e3-9409-3dbc47429e9f",
      "id": [ "de769846-9145-40f8-ab2d-91c0d9b82b27",
       "d5723929-71a0-4dfe-bf03-94d43e358145" ],
      "edge_context": [ "small" ],
      "statement_id": 
      [ "09b05bc0-20ab-11e9-a5b3-9fb3da66a7cb",
       "62671510-20ab-11e9-8cbf-ef11fdb08712" ],
       "weight": 6 
      }
    }
];

    var newArray = objt.map(element => {
      const firstProperty = Object.keys(element)[0];
      let objectInfo = element[firstProperty];
      console.log(objectInfo);
      return objectInfo;
    });


    console.log(newArray);
```

What happens here is, the only field of each object is not named the same (in one object is "a", the next one is "b", and so on) so we need to figure out to get the only property of each object in the initial array, which contains the information you need to put in another array. For doing this. Object.keys() returns you an array of the properties of an object. Considering the scenario in which we only have one property per object, we get it using Object.keys(element)[0].

Finally, we just use .map() to generate a new array.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Object.values(object)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) but it's not supported by IE (there is a polyfill for that). Or would use Object.getOwnPropertyNames (which is supported by IE) to convert the keys to an array and map the array to another which containing the values.

```
var newArray = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object).map(key => object[key])
```